# call to undefined function View::fetch cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, view, cakephp-2.0

I started experimenting with CakePHP version 2.x, I created a default.ctp layout file in View/Layouts inside of which I have codes like:

```
echo $this->fetch('css');
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method View::fetch() in C:\wamp\www\.......
```

I tried creating a block for this css in my view file like:

```
$this->start('css');
$this->Html->css('home_page', null, array('inline' => false));
$this->end();
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method View::start() in C:\wamp\www\.......
```

Any help please?!!!

Thank you

Comment: I was just having this problem! I upgraded to the 2.1 alpha, trying to get it all working again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`View::fetch()`  is available since 2.1, what is your version?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need fetch, start, end for including css, you can just use:

```
$this->Html->css(array('home_page.css'));
//OR
echo $this->fetch('css'); //from version 2.1
```

Ref: [Css CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files)

Answer (score 0):

The book is a little ahead of the release atm! fetch() is from 2.1 code, which is still alpha.

Try generating a default layout using cake's bake tool and study that to see how 2.0 does it, and make sure do you don't follow bits of [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html) which say they are new in 2.1 until you are using the 2.1 codebase.